# Flutter: allow overflow within a container?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is it possible to allow overflow within a container **WITHOUT** making that content scrollable? For example:

```
Container(
  height: 100,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  child: Row(
    children: List.generate(10, (i) => Container(height: 100.0, width: 300).toList();
   ),
)
```

I know that it will theoretically work correctly in release, but I'm looking to suppress the overflow warnings while debugging.

I've tried wrapping the Container() in OverflowBox(), but it still shows the overflow warning. Everything else I've tried makes the list scrollable - it needs to stay fixed.

Comment: Use listviewbuilder widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the List NOT scrollable, use `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` in ListView.
For example

```
ListView.builder(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: 100,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
            return Container(
              height: 100.0,
              width: 300,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              color: Colors.green,
            );
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SingleChildScrollView whith scrollDirection set to Axis.horizontal, Although it works I recommend ListViewBuilder

```
Container(
          height: 100,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Row(
              children: List.generate(
                10,
                (i) => Container(
                  height: 100.0,
                  width: 300,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

using ListviewBuilder

```
ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: 100,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return Container(
                  height: 100.0,
                  width: 300,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  color: Colors.green,
                );
              },
            )
```

EDIT: Wrap widget will do the trick.

```
SizedBox(
        height: 100,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Wrap(
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          direction: Axis.horizontal,
          children: List.generate(
            10,
            (i) => Container(
              height: 100.0,
              width: 300,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ).toList(),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - though I need the content to NOT be scrollable. I'm wondering if that is possible with flutter (without the SDK complaining)?